# Iphone Simulator not showing in developer menu

Tags: iphone, safari, simulator, safari-web-inspector

I recently updated to MacOs Mojave also Safari Technology Preview (Release 67 (Safari 12.1, WebKit 14607.1.9.0.1))

Till now I was in Sierra and I was able to use Web Inspector in safari technology preview to debug Iphone Simulator website, but now is not working so I open a website in iphone simulator, but Iphone is not showing in developer menu in Safari Technology Preview

Does this happen to anyone else ?

Comment: hi @G.L. I am afraid this is not a proper question for StackOverflow. Please, use Meta StackOverflow for discussion type of question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try to cmd + d after check Hardware > keyboard > connect hardware keyboard as below

[image]